# Using a remote database as spring boot datasource

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

I'm trying to configure spring boot datasource as a remote [IBM DB2](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/db2) database. I have added the following configurations in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://<dbhost>:<dbport>/<db>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

I even added the same properties in application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:db2://dashdb-txn-sbox.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:3000/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  driverClassName: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
 jpa:
   properties:
     hibernate:
       dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1). Message: Read timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about configuration than programming.

See this [FAQ for JDBC ERRORCODE -4499](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/faq-jdbc-errorcode-4499-connectivity)

which mentions:

> (A.5) Message: Read timed out
>
> This message is returned when client is waiting for reply from the
>   server and the server did not reply in time. Could be caused by client
>   timeout. Ensure no timeouts set in JDBC driver properties:

```
blockingReadConnectionTimeout=0 (default)
commandTimeout=0 (default)
loginTimeout = 0 (default)
```

> Could also be caused by server or network issues.

If the issue is persistent, ensure you are using the *latest* jdbc Db2 driver ( at the present date that would be version 4.26.14 or higher).

You can use jdbc trace (follow the instructions in IBM Db2 documentation to enable jdbc trace) to look under the covers to see exactly what is happening.

Ensure the remote Db2-server has sufficient compute resources to respond in time. You may need to open a ticket with your cloud vendor (IBM) if the jdbc trace suggests a server side issue that is not under your direct control.

Answer (score 0):

50001 is the usual (default) port number for ssl connections, not 3000 as you have in your question